# MenuItem style with image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, menuitem

I have style for MenuItem:

```
<Style x:Key="mainMenuItem" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Resources:MainMenuItem}">
</Style>
```

How can I set TemplateBinding ImageSource for the Icon Property?
I have MainMenuItem.cs:

```
public class MainMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = 
                              DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                 "ImageSource",
                                                 typeof (ImageSource),
                                                 typeof (MainMenuItem),
                                                 new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just completely ignore the `Icon` property and create a `Setter` for the `Template` in which you define an `Image` in the front which has a template binding to `ImageSource`, or you could register a dependency property changed callback on the `ImageSource` in which you create an `Image` and set it as the `Icon`.